# PHP openssl_digest is taking string hex

Tags: php, openssl, hex, sha256, digest

I want to calculate digest of a hexadecimal value in PHP. When I try to use below method, it produces a output but output is wrong. I need to pass hexadecimal value to `openssl_digest` function as a binary format and I do not know how to do it.

```
openssl_digest("d18b5be5aaa7b5d65c8c4cc1a86b081f6f42c86af071f234f5abeb3c54132fa000000001", "sha256");

Output: e545ada40e461a01c1778e0ec16800234938e448b41d3d437bdb76a900436616
Expected: 5910bcacfd66fba4f880d9f291d243710b08176505015bd8408d8b5c4aaa7a52
```

How to calculate true output?

Comment: can you post the code where you calculate the digest currently?

Comment: https://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm?hex=d18b5be5aaa7b5d65c8c4cc1a86b081f6f42c86af071f234f5abeb3c54132fa000000001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert your hex string to binary with `hex2bin`:

```
openssl_digest(hex2bin("d18b5be5aaa7b5d65c8c4cc1a86b081f6f42c86af071f234f5abeb3c54132fa000000001"), "sha256");
//string '5910bcacfd66fba4f880d9f291d243710b08176505015bd8408d8b5c4aaa7a52' (length=64)
```